# Cannot get curl_exec to work against HTTPS url

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use PHP curl_exec to get some information back from a website that uses HTTPS protocol. I am using PHP on a windows server.

I have hit major issues with trying to get the SSL to work correctly.

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information/live-departures';

$curl_handle=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2000);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$raw = curl_exec($curl_handle);
echo curl_error($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);
```

I got the ca cert from here - https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

I just copied the text from there and saved it as a .pem file using a text editor, that should be OK correct?

The issue I am getting is:

> Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.dublinairport.com:443

I have tried several of the other solutions on stackoverflow including forcing the SSL Version to 1, 2 and 3.

For additional information when I try to hit https:google.com instead I get a different error as follows:

> SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed

So I'm at a loss as to what my next steps should be to try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. Probably not the answer you want to hear. :)

To answer your first question, yes dropping the CA certificates into a file via  text editor is just fine. I thought at first it might be a Windows line ending problem, but I confirmed that curl works with both UNIX and Windows line endings (presumably Mac, too, but that system isn't involved in this question).

To answer your second question. First, I'd add debugging to your script:

```
$url = 'https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information/live-departures';

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

$raw = curl_exec($curl_handle);
if (false === $raw) {
    var_dump(curl_error($curl_handle));
    rewind($verbose);
    var_dump(stream_get_contents($verbose));
} else {
    var_dump($raw);
}

curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Second, I'd check for any intermediaries that are proxying your request. I have only seen "Unknown SSL protocol error" when my connection to a purportedly secure site was intercepted by a non-secure interrogating proxy (think a proxy that requires my browser accept the terms of service before using the wire service). That might be the case here, as evidenced by (a) the error is giving you the *explicit* port number, even though you *implicitly* specified it and (b) it's happening for more than one site.

In short, I don't think this is a code problem. I think this is a network problem from your server outward.